# Jupyter cant run shapely.geometry

Tags: jupyter, shapely, geopandas

Hey so I've managed to get shapely.geometry to run just fine on PyCharm.
But the difficulty here is in getting the import to run on Jupyter notebook.

I have done:

```
import geopandas as gpd
```

This returns shapely.geometry doesn't exist.

I think I know how to fix this through downloading the file 
"Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl" and doing conda install (that)... but it returned that the channel didnt exist...

So I did:

```
conda install --add channels https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
```

(which is where I got the file from) which worked just fine so I then again did "conda install Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl" but it returned:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/win-64/repodata.json>
A simple retry will get you on your way...
```

Tried that, didnt work. Someone please help. Reminder that I successfully installed shapely with all of its modules working through "pip install Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl" WITHIN Pycharm itself.

***EDIT 1***

Im following the textbook "Mastering Geospatial Anlsysis with Python" It got me to download the packages:
gdal
geos
shapely
fiona
pyshp
pyproj
rasterio
geopandas

***EDIT 2***

I dont know what i did but somehow i fixed it... but the thing is, i literally did nothing except take out a shapely file with a long name and kept the one just called "shapely".

If i have files like this

```
gdal-2.2.2-py36hcebd033_1
```

instead of this

```
gdal
```

Is that the problem?????? because if it is, then i dont know how to get files like that they just either appear or they dont.

Comment: Since it seems you are using `conda` to install packages, you don't need to download wheels manually. You can do `conda install shapely`

Comment: Tried it... unfortunetly its not that easy
if i simply do conda install all my stuff... it installs correctly but it still doesnt run in jupyter

Comment: you should create an entirely new environment and install *everything* from conda-forge: `conda create --name=gis python=3.6 notebook geopandas`

Comment: and then activate the environment before launching the jupyter server

Comment: "it installs correctly but it still doesnt run in jupyter" -> that is probably because it is not picking up the correct environment. Be sure to also install ipython/jupyter in the same environment and start jupyter from there

Comment: So this is my setup

C:\Users\lewis\Anaconda3\conda-meta...........................
in here I have Jupyter...shapely.....geos.....geopandas.... .json files .........

Comment: Additionally in  C:\Users\lewis\Anaconda3\pkgs I have the same general files but as folders So with all this i'd imagine that jupyter is indeed in the same environment... but how would i start jupyter from this location? because i only know of starting jupyter from the icon

Answer (score 0):

Shapely is a wrapper of C++ library called [GEOS](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos) that is not installed with the wheel. You should go to the page and install that library.

Or perhaps you have Pycharm for python 2 and Jupyter for python 3 (or vice-versa).

Comment: See EDIT 1 in the question

Answer (score 0):

Running `conda install -c conda-forge geos=3.7.1` worked for me.